# AT command XBee from atmega to disable DIO5 (associated led)

Tags: arduino-uno, xbee, atmega328

I community! I need put ATcommand to my XBee from my atmega using a "xbee library" and a function that I have found in internet. I think the ATComand is "ATD50" to change the DIO5 to value "0" (disabled). My intention is to turn off a led connected into DIO5 (digital input/output 5 (associated led)) after X second/minutes of turning on the device (so that it doesn't turn one again after initial check).

This is a part of my code:

```
#include <XBee.h>
XBee xbee = XBee();
uint8_t atdCmd[] = {'A','T','D','5','0'}; //<---command to put DIO5 to "0" (disabled)
AtCommandRequest atRequest = AtCommandRequest();
AtCommandResponse atResponse = AtCommandResponse();  
void setup()
{ 
delay(30000); 
atRequest.setCommand(atdCmd);
xbee.send(atRequest);
}
void loop()
{}
```

...but it doesn't work!
Thanks guys!

Comment: Looks like you are using Xbee API https://code.google.com/p/xbee-api/
Have you tried putting your Xbee module into API mode? The value ATAP must be set to 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks for aswer david! The API mode is set on mode 2 but doesn't work

Comment: In case .setCommand() needs a null-terminated string, try adding `, \0` after `'0'` or use `uint8_t *atdCmd = (uint8_t *)"ATD50";` to declare it, or `char *atdCmd = "ATD50";` if the API allows.

Comment: Thank you Jwpat7, I try your recomendations, but it doesn't work, other tipps? ...maybe my command is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

finally I solved the problem with this code:

```
uint8_t atdCmd[]={'D','5'};
uint8_t value[]={4};///pongo DIO5 a output LOW
uint8_t length=1;
AtCommandRequest atRequest = AtCommandRequest(atdCmd, value, length);
xbee.send(atRequest);
```

The problem was that I tried to put command with 5 caracters,... and only accepts 2 caracters for "AT command"